# File Geodatabase - Feature Save/Edit/Add Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, file-geodatabase, features, arcgis-10.4

**USING:** ArcMap 10.4 & ArcCatalog 10.4

**FILE LOCATION:** Local

Was wondering if anyone came across the same issue mentioned below, as I'm haven't been able to find an issue like mine elsewhere -

I have a file geodatabase, with several feature classes within it. However, while everything has been fine, there is one issue that for the life of me I cannot fix. For example (and it happens with every feature class), I added about 60-70 line features, added the appropriate attributions, and then finished by clicking "Save Edits" and then "Stop Editing" - and then proceeded to save the document as a whole, verify that I had saved the edits, and then closed the program. The next morning, most of those edits were gone, and considering that it took me 2-3 hours to add those features.

To ensure it wasn't my computer, I installed the trial software on another computer, recreated from scratch the entire file geodatabase, and the feature classes within it. Then I proceeded to create the same features I had in my first installation, saved the edits, stopped editing, saved the arcmap document, and then closed it out. After returning from a meeting, I opened the program and discovered yet again that most of the previous feature additions were gone, with only a few remaining.

Comment: Please edit the question to specify the software you are using (and the version/release).  You should also specify whether the data source was local or networked.

Comment: Alright, edited the question - sorry about that. Thanks!

Comment: Does it work ok, if you try just opening, adding one feature, closing, then reopening?

Comment: Yes, it appears to work well. I've tried several times just in case.